# Trouble error solving

Tags: c++

I am new to this site and new to programming. I am taking a class on programming in college and we were given a code to clear of errors. I am having difficulty with this and would like some help, thanks in advance! The main problems I am having is "loop_counter" and "FunctionFoo" being unidentified and int loop_counter = 1; expecting a ';'

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int UpdateWeatherStation(void)
{
    printf("Updating Weather Station\n\n");
    int foo = 5;
    return foo;    
}

void main(void)
{

    printf("\nTech104 Lab02\n\n")

    int loop_counter = 1; 

    int xyz = FunctionFoo();
    int hjk = FunctionFoo();

    while (loop_counter<10)
    {

        printf("Loop #:%d\n", loop_counter);
        int weatherStatus = UpdateWeatherStation();
        printf("weatherStatus=%d\n", weatherStatus);
        printf("\n\n");

        int user_input = getchar();
        if (user_input == '5')
        {
            printf("User entered 5!!!!!\n");
        }

        loop_counter++;
    }
}

int FunctionFoo(void)
{
    printf("Hello\n\n");
    int abc = 5;

    return abc;
}
```

Comment: The loop_counter error is not uncommon.  Look at the statements before and after that line carefully and you will see something is missing.

Comment: Also, look carefully at the location of the function UpdateWeatherStation and the location of the FunctionFoo compared to where they are called.

Comment: where is the prototype of FunctionFoo?

Comment: As this is not a "real" question in the sense that the answer will benefit anyone else I'll just post this a comment... 1. the line with the printf statement before the `int loop_counter...` is missing a terminating `;` 2. FunctionFoo is defined after it is used and therefore unknown when it is called. It needs to be declared and/or defined before the main function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your code is full of mistakes:

1- where is the prototype of function FunctionFoo?

2- where is the end of statement ';' after printf() in main?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int FunctionFoo(void);
int UpdateWeatherStation(void);



void main(void)
{

    printf("\nTech104 Lab02\n\n");

    int loop_counter = 1; 

    int xyz = FunctionFoo();
    int hjk = FunctionFoo();

    while (loop_counter<10)
    {

        printf("Loop #:%d\n", loop_counter);
        int weatherStatus = UpdateWeatherStation();
        printf("weatherStatus=%d\n", weatherStatus);
        printf("\n\n");

        int user_input = getchar();
        if (user_input == '5')
        {
            printf("User entered 5!!!!!\n");
        }

        loop_counter++;
    }
}

int FunctionFoo(void)
{
    printf("Hello\n\n");
    int abc = 5;

    return abc;
}

int UpdateWeatherStation(void)
{
    printf("Updating Weather Station\n\n");
    int foo = 5;
    return foo;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! As I mentioned earlier, I am very new to programming. Since you are very good at reading I presume, I would assume that you could see that I am new to this language of c++. Something as simple as constructive criticism would be greatly appreciated in the future.